# Type lookups on `this` in a method

Tags: typescript

I am trying to read properties off `this` in a class method, but I can't get TypeScript to look up the type. Instead, the type becomes `this['key']`, which eventually leads to an exception when the type is used with an external library.

```
import { Observable, of, tap } from 'rxjs';

class Foo {
  a = 0;

  b = this.observe('a');

  // 'c' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
  c = this.b.pipe(tap((x) => x));

  observe<K extends keyof this>(key: K): Observable<this[K]> {
    return of(this[key]);
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can make TypeScript narrow down the type to `number` so that the rxjs operation does not cause an exception?

Comment: Don't see the problem. When doing `const x = new Foo().c;`, the type of `x` is correctly inferred as `number`.

Comment: The real world example is much more complex.

It's used in a TypeScript mixin to turn properties into rxjs observables. When the type `Observable<this['a']>` is used to create new observables, TS will throw `ts(7022)`.

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The question is a minimal, reproducible example. Within `Foo`, the member `c` has the type `this['a']`.

Comment: And the type of `this['a']` is `number`; changing the property declaration to `c: number = this.get('a');` does not produce an error. As @FrankFajardo mentioned, you should provide a [mre], because it's currently unclear what your problem is.

Comment: The question was never related to an error, it was whether a method can do type lookups. I felt that the fact that `this['a']` results in an exception when used with an external library just added fluff to the question. It makes the question harder to read, it requires a library to even run, and it is not something I can even fix on my end. Anyhow, I updated the question with some rxjs code to produce the exception I'm struggling with.

Comment: The RxJS library use seems to be material to the question. Even just removing the call to `tap()` resolves the issue: `c = this.b.pipe();`, as does annotating the `pipe()` command: `c = this.b.pipe<this['a']>(tap((x) => x));`